# GKE cluster nodes location

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

A GKE regional cluster deploys 3 GCE instances running the control plane components in 3 different zones (one per zone), and the number of worker nodes duplicated in 3 different zones also. My questions are:

Let's say we have a regional cluster with one worker node, that gives us 3 control plane instances (charged as a single node) and 3 worker nodes each in every zone, then:

1- Do the deployments get run in a single woker node and the other two are only for backup, or do they get spread and run on all worker nodes?

2- Is it possible to control the number of worker nodes like only 2 or 4 or 5? and that to save costs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For no.2 question you can also review this public documentation of GCP [Creating a zonal cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-zonal-cluster#:~:text=In%20the%20Node%20pool%20details%20section%2C%20complete%20the%20following%3A), to understand more.

Comment: I read it and it does not answer my question which is whether I can create a regional cluster with a specified number of worker nodes spread in different zones I specify and not replicated, like for example 5 nodes: 2 in zone 1, 2 in zone 2 and 1 in zone 3, or I only specify the total number of nodes and the zones and let it spread them as it sees fit.

Comment: From regional clusters you can also define which zone and numbers of worker nodes under default-pool config using the Standard cluster. Autopilot clusters are managed by GCP.

Answer (score 0):

1. How many instances of your deployments and how they are spread out depend on a combination of your deployment spec and availability of compute resources.  In order to have multiple instances, you'd typically use a ReplicaSet or StatefulSet.  With a ReplicaSet, you define the number of replicas you want and by default they will be scheduled on any available compute.  If you want to ensure they are spread across zones, you can use topologySpreadConstraints and/or anti-affinity to spread the replicas across zones.
2. Yes.  Typically you'll end up deleting the default nodepool and creating your own nodepools for which you can select which zones will be used as well as the minimum and maximum sizes for the pool.  I'd also recommend enabling cluster autoscaling and/or node auto-provisioning as well.  Also note that starting in GKE 1.23, GKE also supports nodepools with zero nodes as well which works well to limit the number of nodes when combined with cluster autoscaler.

NOTE:  You might also want to consider using GKE in Autopilot mode.  With Autopilot, you don't pay for the nodes; you only pay for the resources used by your deployments.

Comment: For the 2 answer, yes but that would always duplicates the specified number of nodes by the number of the zones specified and what I want is to control the final number of nodes and set them as I want like for example 5 nodes across 2 zones. Is that possible? and for the duplicated nodes, do they incur charges or only the number of specified nodes are charged? Bottom line, I do not want duplication for worker nodes, I want it only for control nodes.